# open or navigate on new Bloc form on pressed event

Tags: flutter, events, listener, bloc

I have 2 Bloc **Registration** and **Login**, Registration click button on the login page.
I want to redirect on Registration page from login's Registration Button click, here is the snippate.
getting an error like this

```
child: new RaisedButton(
          color: Colors.red[800],
          textColor: Colors.white,
          child: new Text(
            'REGISTER',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
          ),
          onPressed: () => BlocListener(
              //bloc: RegistrationPageBloc,
              listener:
                  (BuildContext context, RegistrationFormState state) {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return RegistrationForm();
                }));
              }),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          ),
        ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove bloclistener

```
child: new RaisedButton(
          color: Colors.red[800],
          textColor: Colors.white,
          child: new Text(
            'REGISTER',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
          ),
          onPressed: () => 
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return RegistrationForm();
                })),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Same error; FYI: RegistrationForm is also bloc page.

Comment: can you provide the code of RegistrationForm

Comment: Please check this link
https://file.io/k8o2qVAEVv2a

Comment: after link open page appears with  "The file you requested has been deleted" message

Comment: Did you find anything?

Answer (score 0):

Your parent widget doesn't pass your desirect `registrationBloc` to the child with the `BlocListener`, which results in a context without a provided `RegistrationBloc`.

You need to wrap your parent with a BlocProvider. For example:

```dart
BlocProvider(
 create: (_) => RegistrationBloc(),
 child: RaisedButton(
    child: BlocListener(),
  )
),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
It won't help me, as I mentioned I have 2 different Bloc *LoginBloc* and *RegistrationBloc* and I did use *LoginBloc* in parent already.

Comment: In that case pass your bloc by value by using BlocProvider.value!

Answer (score 0):

You can use two bloc to provide same page with **MultiBlocProvider**

```
MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
           BlocProvider(
                create: (context) => RegistrationBloc(),
           ),
            BlocProvider(
              create: (context) => LoginBloc(),
           ),
           ],
            child: YourPage(),
       );
```

Comment: Thanks for ans but still not working please confirm this code

return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => RegistrationPageBloc(),
          ),
          BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => LoginPageBloc(),
          ),
          BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => FPPageloc(),
          ),
        ],
        child: FPForm(),
      )

Comment: I have a different page for each!

Comment: I can pass bloc to another page with constructor